# Ocelot gateway missing response headers

Tags: asp.net-core, microservices, aggregation, ocelot

I am using Ocelot gateway for routing asp.net core micro-services but in case of aggregation its missing response headers(security header).

Any solution?

Comment: Implement [your own](https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/requestaggregation.html#advanced-register-your-own-aggregators) aggregator and compose the response as you like. Refer [SimpleJsonResponseAggregator.cs](https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot/blob/develop/src/Ocelot/Multiplexer/SimpleJsonResponseAggregator.cs) for sample implementation.

Comment: @Arture looks like this aggregator not synced with latest changes. Can you plz refer any link of custom aggregation example.

Comment: What do you mean? The link I provided is to `development` branch, it means newest.